# Django - How to do a multi page form?

Tags: django, forms

I'm doing a Signup process with 3 steps,

```
1 - (Getting Started), Basic Info
2 - (Checkout), Payment
3 - (Profile Details), choose user and password
```

I've been goggling but I'm not sure what is the best process to do this.

Should I track the data by generating a UUID on the URL?

```
http://some.com/signup/123kslk434435
http://some.com/signup/checkout/123kslk434435
http://some.com/signup/create-account/123kslk434435
```

Or should I do this using sessions?

What the best way of doing it?

Best Regards,
André

Comment: If you do your step 3 first (creating a profile), you can then create a Django user and then sign him in, which will mean you'll have a way of tracking the user across multiple forms. Interested in changing the order or is there a requirement that things are done in this order?

Comment: Hi Bob! The workflow should be in this order. I've read more about the subject and I think the best way is to use cookies or combine cookies with the URL trick. I'm I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [Django Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) is probably what you're after. This will handle creating a session for you (using the  `SessionWizardView`) and then present you at the end of the workflow with each of the completed forms, which you can then process, save to objects etc. as you see fit.

Create each of your forms for each step as such:

```
from django import forms

class BasicInfoForm(forms.Form):
    info_field_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    checkout_field_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

...
```

Then create your view, which will process your forms once they're all done. Be sure to redirect at the end.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

class SignupWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        (process each of your forms, which are contained in form list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/page-to-redirect-to-when-done/')
```

And then connect up the forms with the view in your urlconfig

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contact/$', ContactWizard.as_view([BasicInfoForm, CheckoutForm, ...]))
]
```

See the documentation for creating templates, how to process form_list etc.